# Basic - Manipulating memory with C

Tags: c, file, memory, cs50

I'm starting to learn C and I'm definitely not good at it, I'm doing the CS50 course, week 4 (Memory) and I have to look into a *.raw* for *.jpeg*'s.

When I run my code, the images are created perfectly, in order, blah blah blah, but when I open them, they are blank (One has some part of the image but, not what I'm looking to achieve),

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void makeJPEG(int nof, unsigned char chunk[512]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Just give 1 argument, not less, not more.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("El nombre del archivo es -> %s\n", argv[1]);
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    unsigned char chunk[512];
    int nof = 0;
    while (fread(chunk, sizeof(char), 512, file) == 512)
    {
        if (sizeof(chunk) == (sizeof(char) * 512))
        {
            if (chunk[0] == 0xff && chunk[1] == 0xd8 && chunk[2] == 0xff)
            {
                printf("\n****************************************************\n");
                printf("\n\nProbably a JPEG\n");
                if ((chunk[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
                {
                    printf("Definitely a JPEG\n");
                    char filenameMain[8];
                    makeJPEG(nof, chunk[512]);
                    sprintf(filenameMain, "%03i.jpg", nof);
                    printf("The file -> %s <- was created successfully\n\n", filenameMain);
                    printf("\n****************************************************\n");
                    nof++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not a JPEG\n");
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("\n*Final*\n");
    return 0;
}

void makeJPEG(int nof, unsigned char chunk[512])
{
    FILE* img = NULL;
    //Declaring a String of 8 bytes
    char filename[8];

    //Giving that String the name of the file
    sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", nof);

    //Writing the new jpg file
    img = fopen(filename, "a");
    fwrite(chunk, sizeof(char), 512, img);

    //Closing the image and freeing the memory
    fclose(img);
}
```

I think my problem is with the way I use the "chunk" variable and how I send it to "makeJPEG", but I don't have idea what I'm doing wrong, I repeat, I'm totally a novice.

**PS: Sorry for the mistakes in my English and thanks for the help in advance :)**

Comment: Why you need `while`..`fread` when the header is only in the beginning of file? You have to check only first block (of 512 or even 3 bytes). Also `if (sizeof(chunk) == (sizeof(char) * 512))` is absolutely not necessary.

Comment: What of `fread` reads something but not 512 bytes?

Comment: You do now when it is definitely a jpeg, but what do you print when that test fails?

Comment: That's because I was editing it constantly just to make it work, but yeah, it's not necessary, my bad D:

Comment: When that test fails it just prints "Not a JPEG" and continues to the next block... I guess, that was my idea

Comment: I know, I'm stupid coding, sorry :(

Comment: What is the format of the `.raw` file?

Comment: If `if ((chunk[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)` fails, you print nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`makeJPEG(nof, chunk[512]);` is wrong. That attempts to pass element 512 of `chunk`. Change it to `makeJPEG(nof, chunk);`. That passes the buffer `chunk` (by pointer). Your compiler should have given you a warning message for this. If it did not, turn on warning messages and pay attention to them.

The main loop of your program continues reading from the file into `chunk` and checking each one to see if it is a JPEG. That is wrong. Only the first part of a file will have the indicators that it is a JPEG. To copy the entire file, you should check only the first part and then copy all of it.

Additionally, the loop increments `nof`, and `makeJPEG` opens a new file each time it is called. This would write every chunk of an input file to many different output files, which is not generally useful. If you want your program to copy one JPEG file, then redesign it so that chunks are written to the same file each time, not to a new file. If you want your program to process many input files, you need to redesign it in other ways.

This is useless: `sizeof(chunk) == (sizeof(char) * 512)`. The size of `chunk` is always the size it was defined to be, 512 bytes.

This needs changing: `fread(chunk, sizeof(char), 512, file) == 512`. You need to use `result = fread(chunk, sizeof chunk, 1, file)`, where `result` is previously declared with type `size_t`. Then you need to check `result`. If it is 512 bytes, you have a complete chunk and should write it to the output file and loop to process more chunks. If it is zero, no more data could be read, and you are done with this file (aside from special circumstances we can neglect for now). If it is between zero and 512, you got a partial chunk, which is likely the end of the file. You should write it to the output file, after which you are done with this input file (barring special circumstances).